# Dual Booting Ubuntu along with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, 16.04, 18.04

I have been trying to install the Ubuntu 16_04 version on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 5577). I also tried installing the 18_04 version.

Both of them possess different errors:

1. The 16_04 version while installing through a USB drive, stops as soon as the Ubuntu logo pops up at the beginning of the installation
2. In the 18_04 version, the installation is successful however while booting, after we select Ubuntu, the screen goes black and nothing else happened

The laptop has got a SSD of 128GB, and by default it was MBR partitioned. The above two issues occurred while it was MBR partitioned.

Later I deleted the partitions and installed the Windows 10 using a USB drive which had Windows 10 GPT partitioned. Hence, now my laptop has GPT partitioning. Windows 10 installation was successful after GPT partitioning in the SSD.

I again tried installing both the versions of Ubuntu using the alongside Windows installation option. Now, the Ubuntu 18_04 is installed on the 1TB HDD but has the same above error (screen goes black and nothing else happened). I tried installing 16_04 version which was unsuccessful with the same error again (Ubuntu logo pops up at the beginning of the installation)!

The error reads as "`(sdc) no cache ....`" and some ACPI error.

PC Configuration:

```
SSD: 128 GB
HDD: 1TB
Ram: 8GB
Graphics Card: Nvidia GTX 1050 4GB
Processor: Intel i5 7th Gen
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

To install Ubuntu 16.04 try to create Live USB using [LinuxLive USB Creator](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/).